# R transfer function in a "pipe"-form

Tags: r, pipe

I have a dataframe for Bitcoin time series data with 3 columns: the date, the closing price (Close) and the return.

```
> head(BTC.USD)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
Date       Close                       Return
<date>     <dbl>                        <dbl>
1 2015-12-31  430.                      NA     
2 2016-01-01  434.                       0.940 
3 2016-01-02  434.                      -0.0622
4 2016-01-03  431.                      -0.696 
5 2016-01-04  433.                       0.608 
6 2016-01-05  431.                      -0.489
```

Now I want to calculate the standard deviation for the return.
I used the basic function and this function works:

```
> sd(BTC.USD$Return, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 4.10426
```

Now I want to transform it in a "pipe"-form, so I can implement that into a apply-function, for example. But it doesn't work:

```
library(tidyverse)
> BTC.USD %>% sd(Return, na.rm = TRUE)
Error in sd(., Return, na.rm = TRUE) : unused argument (Return)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `BTC.USD %>% pull(Return) %>% sd(na.rm = TRUE)` probably. This extracts column `Return` and then applies `sd` just like in `BTC.USD$Return %>% sd(na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you!